# How to bind to WPF DataGrid row class instance and not it's property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I need to decide an icon for a DataGrid-column for a row and thought I let a converter do it. Converter would just get the whole row and then decide by multiple properties which xaml-geometry to return

```
 <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedObjectsMmsDataItems}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TypeImageColumnTemplate" >
                <Label Style="{StaticResource DataGridIconColumnLabel}">
                    <Path Data="{Binding???, Converter={StaticResource MmsDataToPathConverter}}" />
                </Label>
            </DataTemplate>
           <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StrIcon}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource TypeImageColumnTemplate}" Width="Auto"/>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the `DataGridRow`

```
<Path Data="{Binding ., RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Converter={StaticResource MmsDataToPathConverter}}" />
```

This will give you the `Item` (eg; Employee) presented by that row.

```
<Path Data="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Converter={StaticResource MmsDataToPathConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of your binding is that of an IEnumerable or Collection such as a class structure, you should be able to do by exposing your own custom property and doing all the manipulation of it from there.  Something like

```
public class YourClass
{
   public YourClass()
   {...}

   public int SomeField { get; set;}
   public string OtherField {get; set;}
   ...

   public whateverDataType YourNewPropertyToBindTo
   {
      get { if( SomeField == 1 && OtherField == "Test" )
               return "X";

            if( SomeField == 2  && OtherFIeld == "SomethingElse"
               return "Y";

            return "Z"; // as a default return value. }
   }
}
```

Then, you can access all the properties and proper data types directly from your record / class structure source.  Hope this option helps.

Comment: thanks! i don't know if I explained myself properly, but I found how this is done. my problem was comma (,) before Converter. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is done with following XAML. When there's only word Binding without anything else, comma should be left out before Converter.

```
 <Path Data="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MmsDataToPathConverter}}"
```